# What data type should be used as an alternative for boolean in Postgres, HSQL, MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, hsqldb

We are using Oracle, Postgres, HSQL, MSSQL.

Since boolean is not supported by Oracle, we are using number(1,0) . So, other databases are getting affected.

What is the data type to be used in Postgres, HSQL, MSSQL, when we cannot use boolean data type?

For example: bit ?

Comment: In MSSQL it's an option to use the bit data type (0,1, optionally NULL)

Comment: The only **universal** workaround for a missing boolean is  a `number(1)` with a check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

`number` and `*-int`were the most common methods  I've encountered so far, whereas `number` was used more frequently.

Edit:

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentionied, you're probably fine using number.

Answer (score 0):

In data types

SQL ->  Postgresql
Boolean -> Number , Smallint

Also include  instead of @Type(type = "java.lang.Boolean")

Include @Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")